# (intval(floatval("18.99") * 100)) ? 18.98

Tags: php

Why Below  code is giving this answer instead of 1899 and how can I fix it

```
echo (intval(floatval("18.99") * 100));
```

answer 1898
but

```
echo (intval(floatval(18.99) * 100));
```

is 1899

So how can we fix below code

```
$a = "18.99";
echo (intval((floatval($a) * 100)));
```

and the answer become 1899

Comment: `echo "18.99" * 100;` this works

Comment: but some time the variable we get is 018.9985 so it need be fixed

Comment: `echo "018.9985" * 100;` // 1899.85

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) and then read the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and especially that big pink WARNING

Answer (score 2):

It's known issue. http://php.net/manual/function.intval.php#7707
Fast solution:

```
echo (intval(strval(floatval("18.99") * 100)));
```